# How to disable/enable checkboxes in dynamic table based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have a html table that I am dynamically generating from a JSON file. This table contains rows with a dropdown list and a checkbox. If the default value in the dropdown list is selected the checkbox should be disabled otherwise it should be enabled. I believe the following code should do what I want.

```
$(function() {
$('td select').change(function () {
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', $( 'select option:selected' ).val()=='Default');
}).change();});
```

However, when I run it in my code only the first row of the table demonstrates the functionality I'm looking for. Because the table is dynamically generated from a JSON I don't believe a loop is an option. Similar questions have been asked here but they won't work for dynamically generated tables. The fiddle attached below is similar to what I am trying to implement and it seems as though my logic is the same. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

http://jsfiddle.net/3RRLP/2/

Comment: Here you find more info: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/239631-using-getelementsbytagname-on-json-object/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the element doesn't exist in the DOM yet when the handler is attached, you can try:

```
 $(function() {
    $('body').on('change', 'td select', function() {
        console.log(this.id);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', $('select option:selected').val() == 'Default');
    }).change();
});
```